# Capture the last word on each line

Tags: regex, string, sed

I have a file that doesn't have the correct spacing and I would like to add a space between the dollar amount and the word right beside it, i.e., `2342.20Hello`.

I tried using `sed` to resolve this issue but it didn't seem to work.

I tried this command but it doesn't seem to work.

```
sed -r 's/([0-9].*)\.([a-zA-Z].*) /\1 \2/g' /tmp/testfile2.txt
```

I was expecting the file that has:

```
2234.3Hello
8938.3HeyYou
1239.0New
```

To look like this:

```
2234.3 Hello
8938.3 HeyYou
1239.0 New
```

I'm okay with `Perl` or `sed` commands to accomplish the above.

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regexp is trying to match on a `.` followed by `[a-zA-Z]` - no strings like that exist in your input, there's always a digit between each `.` and letter.

Using any sed:

```
$ sed 's/\.[0-9]*/& /' file
2234.3 Hello
8938.3 HeyYou
1239.0 New
```

Answer (score 4):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples in GNU `awk` please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -v RS='[a-zA-Z]+' 'RT{sub(/^\n/,"");print $0,RT}'  Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using `sed` with `-E` option try following.

```
sed -E 's/^([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)([^0-9]+)$/\1 \2/' Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `sed -E 's/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)([a-zA-Z]+)/\1 \2/g'`

The regex takes input text and looks for occurrences of decimal numbers followed by alphabetic characters. It then replaces each occurrence with the decimal number, a space, and the alphabetic characters. The -E option enables extended regular expressions, allowing the use of + to match one or more occurrences and () to capture specific parts of the pattern for later use in the replacement text.

Comment: An alternative approach: `sed 's/[A-Z]/ &/'`

Comment: The `g` at the end is doing nothing useful given the OPs input.

Answer (score 3):

Using perl with a case insensitive match using `/i`

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\K[A-Z]/ $&/i' file
```

Where the pattern matches

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\K[A-Z]
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `\K` Forgets what has been matched so far
- `[A-Z]` Match a single char A-Z

The replacement  `$&` is a space followed by what is matched (the single char A-Z)

---

***OR*** If you (as in the title of the post) want to capture/match the last "word" on each line, and in this case starting with `[A-Z]`, you can use an anchor `\Z`

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\K[A-Z]\S*\Z/ $&/i' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\../& /' file
```

Place a space following a decimal point and one digit.

Answer (score 2):

Use either of the following two Perl one-liners:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's{\A[\d.]+}{$& }' infile
```

or

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's{[^\W\d_].*}{ $&}' infile
```

For example, for this input file:

```
2234Hello
2234.3Hello
2234.30Hello
```

this will be the output:

```
2234 Hello
2234.3 Hello
2234.30 Hello
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`. If you want to skip writing a backup file, just use `-i` and skip the extension.

Here,
`s{PATTERN}{REPLACEMENT}` : change `PATTERN` to `REPLACEMENT`.
`\A` : the beginning of the string.
`[\d.]+` : a digit or a period (`.`), repeated 1 or more times.  Matches numbers in the context of your question.
`$&` : the matched pattern.
`[^\W\d_]` : any letter: `[...]` is a character class, `^` is a `not` operator inside the character class, `\W` is non-word character, `\d` is a digit. So, in effect, this is a character class that is a word character but not a digit or underscore, so a letter.
`.*` : any character repeated 0 or more times.

**See also:**

- [`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
- [`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
- [`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
- [`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)